# Get new text from contentEditable DOM elements

Tags: jquery, events, contenteditable

How can I (with Javascript) get the new content from a `contentEditable` DOM element on a page. Would it be as simple as using jQuery in such as way:

```
$("#content").on("keyup", ".editable", function(e){
  var newText = $(this).text();
  console.log("New text is: "+newText);
});
```

Comment: currently what output you are getting?

Comment: I should have done this in JSFiddle to experiment, it was a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ysLPq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple as I was (admittedly) being lazy and asking on here. Here's my JSFiddle for those in the future to see: http://jsfiddle.net/ysLPq/. See code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keyup", ".editable", function(){
        console.log($(this).text()); 
    });
});
```